# SQL - find count based on 2 fields

Tags: sql, oracle, count, duplicates

I have a scenario where I have 1 table. 
The data for the table is like:

```
CATEGORY_TYPE       CATEGORY_TYPE_DESC  RETL_ID
SUPPLIER_XREF       SUPPLIER_XREF       21731
SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF  SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF  21731
```

I want  to find the count where RETL_ID occurs twice but one record is of SUPPLIER_XREF and other record is of SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF.

I tried with this, but this doesn't return any record.

```
select RETL_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
WHERE 
CATEGORY_TYPE IN ('SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF') 
AND CATEGORY_TYPE IN ('SUPPLIER_XREF') 
GROUP BY RETL_ID
HAVING COUNT (*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the distinct occurrences of CATEGORY_TYPE:

```
SELECT RETL_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CATEGORY_TYPE)
FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
WHERE CATEGORY_TYPE IN ('SUPPLIER_XREF', 'SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF') 
GROUP BY RETL_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CATEGORY_TYPE) = 2;
```

If you want CATEGORY_TYPE to have only these 2 values and no other value:

```
SELECT RETL_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CATEGORY_TYPE)
FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
GROUP BY RETL_ID
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CATEGORY_TYPE) = 2
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY_TYPE NOT IN ('SUPPLIER_XREF', 'SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.RETL_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM RFI_XREF_DVM a, RFI_XREF_DVM b
WHERE 
A.CATEGORY_TYPE IN ('SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF') 
AND b.CATEGORY_TYPE IN ('SUPPLIER_XREF') and a. RETL_ID = b.RETL_ID
GROUP BY a.RETL_ID
HAVING COUNT (*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT RETL_ID, 
COUNT(1) -- represent 2 for 21731 as per your sample data. If you want it 1 then use distinct retl_id instead of 1 in count
FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
GROUP BY 
RETL_ID
HAVING
SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY_TYPE = 'SUPPLIER_XREF' 
THEN 1 END) = 1 AND
SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY_TYPE = 'SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF' 
THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count, then one method is to use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT RETL_ID
      FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
      GROUP BY RETL_ID
      HAVING LISTAGG(CATEGORY_TYPE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CATEGORY_TYPE) = 'SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF,SUPPLIER_XREF'
     ) r;
```

Or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT RETL_ID
      FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
      GROUP BY RETL_ID
      HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY_TYPE = 'SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
             SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY_TYPE = 'SUPPLIER_XREF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
     ) r;
```

If you want *exactly* two matches, you cannot filter before the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have RETL_ID that appeard at least twice you can use this:

```
 select RETL_ID, COUNT(retl_id)
    FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
    WHERE CATEGORY_TYPE in ('SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF', 'SUPPLIER_XREF')
    GROUP BY RETL_ID
    HAVING COUNT(retl_id)>= 2;
```

If exactly twice then:

```
select RETL_ID, COUNT(retl_id)
        FROM RFI_XREF_DVM
        WHERE CATEGORY_TYPE in ('SUPPLIER_SITE_XREF', 'SUPPLIER_XREF')
        GROUP BY RETL_ID
        HAVING COUNT(retl_id)= 2;
```